# Laravel 8 - Limit joined tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a data structure as follows:

##### `User`

- `id`

##### `Collection`

- `user_id`
- `game_id`

##### `Game`

- `id`
- `status`

In my models I have the relationships as such:

```php
User::hasMany(Collection)
Collection::belongsTo(Game)
Game::hasMany(Collection)
```

So what I'm trying to do is get a list of users and include all associated games via the collection table. But I want to include only those games that have a particular status. The code I'm using (which isn't working) is as follows:

```php
User::with('collections.game')->whereHas('collections.game', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('status', '<>', 'denied');
})->get()
```

My problem is that all game records are getting returned, including those with the `denied` status. I was reading around and it seems like the above should work but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `whereHas('collections.game', ...)`. You must do a `whereHas` of a `whereHas`:

```php
User::with('collections.game')
    ->whereHas('collections', function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->whereHas('game', function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('status', '<>', 'denied');
        })
    })
    ->get()
```

Comment: that works.  Thank you very much for your reply.  Could you point me to the section of the documentation that discusses this in more detail so I can better understand *why* it works?  I've seen references to `whereHas` in the docs but I'm more interested in the nesting and how that plays a part.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need a filter on your `with()` clause because `whereHas()` will filter users data only but the eager loaded relations will not have that filter included automatically.

```
User::with(['collections.game' => function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', '<>', 'denied');
    }])
    ->whereHas('collections.game', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', '<>', 'denied');
    })->get()
```